# Swift: Is it possible to use delegation when both views aren't in direct connection with each other?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have three ViewController: ViewController1, ViewController2 and ViewController3.

ViewController1 pushes ViewController2 on the screen and both views can interact with each other through delegation.

ViewController2 pushes ViewController3 on the screen.

Now is it possible to establish a delegation between ViewController1 and ViewController3? I want ViewController3 to be able to manipulate a label of ViewController1.

Comment: `ViewController2` can act as a proxy or controller between `ViewController1` and `ViewController3`, passing information between them - if needed

Comment: best way in this scenario would be Notification Pattern.

Comment: You could use NotificationCenter if you don't want to use ViewController2 as a man-in-the-middle passing messages along.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way in this scenario would be `Notification` Pattern

```
  // Notification posting
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "fromViewController3"), object: nil, userInfo: myDict) 


 // Register in ViewController1 to receive notification in your class ViewController1
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.manipulateMyLabel(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "fromViewController3"), object: nil)

 // handle notification
 func manipulateMyLabel(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print(notification.userInfo ?? "")
        if let dict = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary? {
            if let newString = dict["labelValue"] as? String {
               // user newString to update the label text or something.
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: can you clarify why it's the best way in this scenario? Thanks in advance for your reply